# PayPal Express Checkout Error 10623

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, error-code

(All sensitive information will be replaced by *'s)

I'm having issues doing multiple authorizations on my order transaction through the paypal Express checkout. My order transaction looks as such:

**PARTNER=*****&VENDOR=*****&USER=*****&PWD=*****&TENDER=P&TRXTYPE=O&ACTION=D&AMT=186.76&PAYERID[13]=*************&TOKEN=************&COMMENT1=w2279400&COMMENT2=**

Which is approved:

**RESULT=0&PNREF=B7PP7D067BC7&RESPMSG=Approved&AVSADDR=Y&AVSZIP=Y&TOKEN=*****&PAYERID=****&PPREF=*****&CORRELATIONID=ebf6245de4f4e&PAYMENTTYPE=None&PENDINGREASON=order**

I then do my first authorization, followed by a delayed capture:

**PARTNER=*****&VENDOR=*****&USER=*****&PWD=*****&TENDER=P&TRXTYPE=A&ORIGID=B7PP7D067BC7&AMT=92.32&COMMENT1=I2279400&COMMENT2=**

**PARTNER=*****&VENDOR=*****&USER=*****&PWD=*****&TENDER=P&TRXTYPE=D&ORIGID=*****&AMT=92.32&CAPTURECOMPLETE=N&COMMENT1=I2279400&COMMENT2=**

These return approved. I then try an do my second authorization:

**PARTNER=*****&VENDOR=*****&USER=*****&PWD=*****&TENDER=P&TRXTYPE=A&ORIGID=B7PP7D067BC7&AMT=94.44&COMMENT1=M2279400&COMMENT2=**

However, this one fails with the following:

**RESULT=12&PNREF=B7PP7D067BE3&RESPMSG=Declined: 10623-Maximum number of authorization allowed for the order is reached.**

I can't seem to find anything really related to this message, other than it can be prompted by providing an amount of 106.23(which I'm clearly not doing)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You ***ed out the ORIGID of the first capture: was this capture referencing the authorization that was just generated, or the original order? This first capture should probably be against the authorization just generated, and should be captureocmplete YES (thus closing that authorization but leaving the order open). If you are doing that, then I don't know...

Comment: Geewiz - The ORIGID of the first capture does match the authorization that was just generated. I've tried setting it to capturecomplete=y, but when I try and create a second authorization against the order, I receive the following error: 
RESULT=12&PNREF=B1PP7EA9ECBF&RESPMSG=Declined: 10620-Order has already been voided, expired or completed.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what you are seeing then (and I wrote much of PayPal's original code in this area). From the parameter lists you are showing it seems you are doing Express Checkout for Payflow; it is entirely possible that there is Payflow-specific limitation (or bug) that is stopping you.... if it's an option for you, you may want to try calling Express Checkout APIs directly to see if the problem goes away... then call PayPal.